# How to update some fields only using cancancan and activeadmin gem

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activeadmin, cancancan

I am using activeadmin with cancancan gem. Where I need to update only 2 fields from user model.

For ex. If we can say, I have User model with name, email, is_admin, is_active.

But from admin, I need to create ability like that where I can only update is_admin and is_active attributes of a User model.

Right now I am trying with this but it's not working:

`can [:read, :update], User, :attributes => [:is_admin, :is_active]`

Comment: do you have separate model for admin and user?

Comment: yes. AdminUser and User is separate model

Comment: in user model you have field called `role` filed

Comment: try this `can [:read,:update], User, is_active: true,is_admin:true`

Answer (score 0):

In this cancan not help, cancan used to authorize resource. You need to create custom active admin form to achieve this. For this you can take reference [here](https://activeadmin.info/5-forms.html).